# "At the horizon" or "on the horizon"?

Tags: prepositions

What's the right preposition to use with "horizon"?

Example:

> A cruiser cut through waves **at** the horizon.
>   A cruiser cut through waves **on** the horizon.

I get both results on Google: [waves on the horizon](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22waves%20on%20the%20horizon.%22&oq=%22waves%20on%20the%20horizon.%22&gs_l=serp.3...50525.50612.0.50763.2.2.0.0.0.0.117.117.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.0.0.a2fWlupFNR4)/[waves at the horizon](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22waves%20at%20the%20horizon.%22&oq=%22waves%20at%20the%20horizon.%22&gs_l=serp.3...19362.23233.0.23461.9.9.0.0.0.0.134.726.3j4.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..9.0.0.W2HdMJTgqnk).

So I'm not very sure which version to use.

Comment: You usually say on the horizon.

Answer (score 1):

Go with "on". In my experience it's by far the more common option. Particularly since, when you think of it, the "horizon" is not really a place you can be *at*.